# How may I design a centrifugal fan?

Tags: design

I have customized a fan for our centrifuge. How may I design it? Can you recommend me some software / resources ?

These are the the specifications:

Type : Radial

Capacity : 5000 Nm3/h

Head : 100 millibar

Speed : 2925 RPM